# Proving derivative of CDF of $\mu$ is $0$ a.e. on $\mu$-null set, and an analogue in $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to solve the following problem (Klenke's *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course* 2nd ed., Exercise 13.1.6):

> Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $\mathbb R^d$ and let $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ be a $\mu$-null set. Let $C \subset \mathbb R^d$ be bounded, convex and open with $C = -C$. Then,
> $$
> \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu(x + rC)}{r^d} = 0 \quad \textrm{for }\lambda^d\textrm{-a.e. }x \in A.
> $$
> Conclude that if $F$ is the distribution of a Stieltjes measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ and if $A \in \mathcal B(R)$ is a $\mu$-null set, then $\frac{d}{dx} F(x) = 0$ for $\lambda$-a.e. $x \in A$.

The problem suggests using the following result:

> Let $C \subset \mathbb R^d$ be open, bounded, and convex with $C = -C$. Assume that $\mathcal U = \left\{ x + rC : x \in \mathbb R^d, r > 0\right\}$ is such that $W := \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal U} U$ has finite Lebesgue measure $\lambda^d(W)$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist finitely many pairwise disjoint sets $U_1, \ldots, U_n \in \mathcal U$ such that
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda^d(U_i) > \frac{1-\epsilon}{3^d} \lambda(W).
> $$

**What I've tried:** For the first part, assume first that $\lambda^d(A) < \infty$ (the  case where $\lambda^d(A) = \infty$ follows by $\sigma$-finiteness). For each $x \in A$, by outer regularity of Lebesgue measure, there is $r = r_x > 0$ such that $W = \bigcup_{x \in A} \left(x + r_x C\right)$ has finite volume. So for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a finite collection $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in A$ and $r_1 > \cdots > r_n > 0$ for which $\left\{ x_i + r_i C\right\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ is pairwise disjoint and for which
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda^d\left(x_i + r_i C\right) = \lambda^d(C) \sum_{i=1}^n r_i^d > \frac{1-\epsilon}{3^d} \lambda(W).
$$
Since $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $\mathbb R^d$, $\mu$ may be shown to be outer regular, so that might have something to do with it. But I'm pretty stuck.

For the second part, if $\mu$ is a Stieltjes measure on $\mathbb R$ with distribution $F$, that means $F$ is positive, monotone increasing, and right-continuous, with $\mu((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$. If we let $C = (-1/2,1/2) \subset \mathbb R$, since $\mu$ is Radon, I've been able to show for $\lambda$-a.e. $x \in A$:
\begin{align*}
0 &= \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu((x-\frac r 2, x+\frac r 2))}{r}\\ &= \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu((x-\frac r 2+\epsilon, x+\frac r 2-\epsilon])}{r} \qquad \textrm{(by lower semicontinuity of $\mu$)} \\
&= \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{F(x+\frac 1 2(r-\epsilon)) - F(x-\frac 1 2(r-\epsilon))}{r-\epsilon}
\end{align*}
If $F$ were continuous in a neighborhood of $x$, then this would obviously be equal to the derivative, but it's not clear to me why $F$ is continuous in a neighborhood of a.e. point. Thoughts?

**EDIT** See comment for a good resource towards a solution.

Comment: The following paper has a good idea for how to solve it for $d=1$, and it extends easily to arbitrary dimension using the suggested result above: https://conf.math.illinois.edu/~loeb/LocalMax.pdf